# Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to_sql (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am writing a `DataFrame` of shape `(500K, 10)` into my local postgres database. Currently, it is taking about 60 sec to write. I want to speed this up. I did some research around and found out that using `method = 'multi'` and `chunksize` parameters of `to_sql` has helped folks to bring down the write time drastically. It's not the case with me though. My write times almost remained the same or were reduced barely.

In addition, I also tried using `fast_executemany` (snippet below)

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:Opex123@localhost:5432/Annual_Business_Plan_Baseline_8_155')
schema = 'public'

####
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
        cursor.commit()
####
```

but it is giving following error -
`psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'fast_executemany'`

Anyone who successfully navigated through this challenge?